# How to show audio waveforms in react-native from live audio

Tags: react-native, agora.io

In my app I am joining a live audio broadcast using Agora SDK, but I am really struggling how to visualize this audio in my react-native app. There is no package that support this feature and agora docs are not that good. anyone have an idea on how to achieve that ?